# How to call a namer range using a variable to define the name

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, named-ranges

According the documentation, any quoted text names can be defined by a variable
If I define

```
Set xlsDataSource = Application.Workbooks("New_TOR_V1.xlsm").Names("MyRange").RefersToRange
```

it works as expected
If I use

```
Dim S as string
S="MyRange"

Set xlsDataSource = Application.Workbooks("New_TOR_V1.xlsm").Names(S).RefersToRange
```

it also work well

but using

```
Dim Arr() as string
Arr(1)="MyRange"
Set xlsDataSource = Application.Workbooks("New_TOR_V1.xlsm").Names(Arr(1)).RefersToRange
```

gives an error message

and also

```
Set xlsDataSource = Application.Workbooks("New_TOR_V1.xlsm").Names(Cstr(Arr(1))).RefersToRange
```

gives an error message

Why does an array element cause an error and how can I solve this?

I do need to use an array?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Pass the named range into the array or use the array to fill the named range?

Comment: Or are you trying to name a range via the elements of the array?

Answer (score 0):

### Declare your array with size - `Dim Arr(1) as String`

I'm not entirely sure what your specific application is, but **the array needs a size before it can be used** -

```
Sub test()
'One number indicates one dimension and starts at **0** See footnote
Dim Arr(1) As String
Arr(1) = "MyRange2"
Range("A2").Name = Arr(1)
End Sub
```

[footnote](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa140487%28v=office.10%29.aspx)

If you don't know it yet, you'll need to `redim` it:

```
Sub test()

Dim Arr() As String
'Do stuff to get a number 
ReDim Arr(1)
Arr(1) = "MyRange3"
Range("A3").Name = Arr(1)

End Sub
```

In your example, I've broken it up, but it works like this:

```
Sub test()

Dim Arr() As String
ReDim Arr(1)
Arr(1) = "MyRange"
Range("A1").Name = Arr(1)

Set xlsdatasource = ThisWorkbook.Names("MyRange").RefersToRange
MsgBox (xlsdatasource.Address)

End Sub
```

Gives me `$A$1` in the msgbox.

Replace the "A1" with "A1:C1" and the msgbox gives me `$A$1:$C$1`.

---

#### A more complex example with the same restrictions

For A1:A6 reading -

```
this
is
a
one
dimensional
array
```

This compiles and runs as well:

```
Sub test()

Dim Arr() As String

Dim j As Integer
j = [counta(A1:A10)]
ReDim Arr(j - 1) 

Dim i As Integer
  For i = 0 To 5
  Arr(i) = Cells(i + 1, 1)
  Next

Dim rng As Range

  For i = 0 To 5
  Set rng = Range(Cells(i + 2, i + 5), Cells(i + 2, i + 8))
  rng.Name = Arr(i)
  Next

Set xlsdatasource = ThisWorkbook.Names(Arr(3)).RefersToRange
MsgBox (xlsdatasource.Address)

End Sub
```

and msgbox displays `$H$5:$K$5`.

Changing this:

```
Set xlsdatasource = ThisWorkbook.Names(Arr(3)).RefersToRange 
MsgBox (xlsdatasource.Address)
```

to this:

```
Set xlsdatasource = ThisWorkbook.Names("one").RefersToRange
MsgBox (xlsdatasource.Address)
```

also returns msgbox displaying `$H$5:$K$5`.

---

#### A note

If cell `A4` read `1` instead of `one`, I couldn't `Dim Arr() as String` because "1" doesn't begin with a *letter* or *underscore*.

I could use `_1` or `Dim Arr() as Variant`, but I couldn't actually name a range "1" because it's an invalid value for *naming*.

Comment: @Nout if you got your question answered, please click the green checkmark next to the answer that helped you. This will mark the question as *solved* for anyone that's looking for something similar, or for anyone that's looking for questions to answer.